# D3 stacked area chart stack function

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a stacked area chart and running into an issue with the stack function.  The x axis is date, the y axis is count and the area is buildResult.

Here is the code:

```
var stack = d3.layout.stack()
          .offset("zero")
          .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
          .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
          .y(function(d) { return d.count; });

// Loop through the data and add elements
data.result.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = new Date(d._id.year, d._id.month-1, d._id.day);
});

// Nest by name aka status
var nested = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d._id.buildResult; });

// Create the layers
var layers = stack(nested.entries(data.result));
```

The raw data looks like:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "month" : 1,
                                "day" : 20,
                                "year" : 2014,
                                "buildResult" : "FAILURE"
                        },
                        "count" : 27
                },
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "month" : 1,
                                "day" : 20,
                                "year" : 2014,
                                "buildResult" : "SUCCESS"
                        },
                        "count" : 93
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

The error I am getting is from the layers object:

```
Cannot read property 1 of undefined
```

The `nested.entries(data.result)` object is not null so I'm not sure what is going on.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: hard without seeing more code...but should it not be `.key(function(d) {return d._id.buildResult;});`?

Comment: Yes, I copied the wrong line.  I have it as you have it, but still getting the error.  Will fix the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue - my data was not formatted correctly, specifically the 2D array I was passing to stack() was not all the same length.